# How to get integers values from a mixed string

Tags: java, string

Say I have a string :

```
String words= "28282 Hello, my name is potato, my age is 245 112 274 141 bla bla bla etc";
```

Is there any way in java to get only the age `245 112 274 141` without having to use [substring()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) . Because as my string's length in which I'm working on are inconsistent so I cannot use the `substring()` method

Comment: Is there a reason 28282 is not included? Are the numbers always next to each other?

Comment: @Dukeling Yes I am trying to figure out a way how to exclude the ID 28282 while only getting 245 112 274 141

Comment: @Dukeling substring() is also a JAVA method, but I will fix it , Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Streams (Java 8+), it's quite simple:

```
Stream.of("28282 Hello, my name is potato, my age is 245 112 274 141 bla bla bla etc"
   .replaceAll("^(\\d*\\s*)?(.*)", "$2").split("\\s+"))
 .filter(part -> part.matches("^\\d+$"))
 .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Comment: Might be simpler to replace the regex with a call to [`Char.isDigit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#compare-char-char-)?

Comment: Could you elaborate? What about numbers containing more than one char?

Comment: Whoops, my link was incorrect, should be: [`Character.isDigit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit-int-). Has two variations, the older taking a `char`, the newer taking an `int` for [code point](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point). And Nevermind… I see now you are breaking on SPACE, I was thinking character-by-character comparison.

Answer (score 2):

you can use regex as `words.replaceAll(".*age\\D*([\\d\\s]+).*","$1").split("\\s+")`

This will fetch all the digits as string , Optionally you can split the to convert them into an array of numbers
[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/nFfHYf/2)

`.*age\\D*([\\d\\s]+).*` : `.*` match anything, match `age` then match 0 or more non-digit number

`([\\d\\s]+).*` : match and capture, 1 or more `(` digit and space `)` represented as `$1` then match anything till line break

[**Java Demo**](https://ideone.com/6LAhyE)